Slow loading of the python code editor in a React-py application
I am developing an educational app with Next.js and react-py. The idea is that you study the theoretical material in little parts, and around each paragraph of text, you can run a Python code  in a cell to test your knowledge or practice.
I created a code editor as a separate component using React-py. In my application, there is no server - everything works on the client-side. I have many problems, but one of the main ones is the unpredictable rendering. Sometimes on some computers, the code editor loads immediately, sometimes after about 30 seconds, and sometimes it doesn't load at all. Has anyone else encountered this?
Here's the code of my component with the code cell:
"use client";

function PythonCompiler() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const {
    runPython,
    stdout,
    stderr,
    isLoading,
    isReady,
    isRunning,
    isAwaitingInput,
    sendInput,
  } = usePython();

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.serviceWorker
      .register("/react-py-sw.js")
      .then((registration) =>
        console.log(
          "Service Worker registration done!: ",
          registration.scope
        )
      )
      .catch((err) =>
        console.log("Service Worker registration не удалась :(    ): ", err)
      );
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // await ensurePyodideHttp(); 
    runPython(input);
  };

  const handleEditorChange = useCallback((val: string, viewUpdate: any) => {
    console.log("val:", val);
    setInput(val);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Flex justify="center" pt={5} pb={1}>
        <div className="relative color-red mb-10 flex flex-col">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="p-4 sm:w-full md:min-w-[43em] bg-gray-800 rounded-md shadow-lg shadow-gray-700/50 width-100%">
              <CodeMirror
                value={input}
                height="100%"
                width="100%"
                extensions={[python()]}
                onChange={handleEditorChange}
                theme={dracula}
                style={{ fontSize: "1.2em" }}
                placeholder="Здесь можно писать и запускать код"
              />
            </div>

            <input
              type="submit"
              value={!isRunning ? "Запуск кода" : "В процессе..."}
              disabled={isLoading || isRunning}
              className={`px-4 my-3 py-2 rounded-md text-white font-semibold 
    ${
      isLoading || isRunning
        ? "bg-gray-400 cursor-not-allowed"
        : "bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-600 focus:ring-opacity-50"
    }
  `}
            />
          </form>
          {isLoading ? <p>Loading...</p> : <p>Ready!</p>}
          {isAwaitingInput && (
            <form
              onSubmit={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                const form = e.target as HTMLFormElement;
                const inputElement = form.elements.namedItem(
                  "input"
                ) as HTMLInputElement;
                if (inputElement) {
                  sendInput(inputElement.value);
                  inputElement.value = "";
                }
              }}
            >
              
              <Input
                name="input"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Ввод: "
                size="md"
                borderColor="gray.300"
                focusBorderColor="blue.500"
                borderRadius="md"
                mb={3}
              />
              <Button my={2} type="submit" colorScheme="blue" size="md">
                Input
              </Button>
            </form>
          )}

            <code>
              <Text sx={{ userSelect: "none" }} color={"gray.500"}>
                Result:{""}
              </Text>
              {stdout}
            </code>
          
            <code>
              <Text sx={{ userSelect: "none" }} color={"gray.500"}>
                Error:{""}
              </Text>
              {stderr}
            </code>
          
        </div>
      </Flex>
    </>
  );
}

export default PythonCompiler;


Can you help me? I'm just a beginner developer and I can't understand what's wrong so far...
I read something in the console about pyodide-http and installed the module, but I didn't notice anything changing.
 const ensurePyodideHttp = async () => {
    if (isReady) {
      try {
        await runPython(`
          import micropip
          await micropip.install("pyodide-http")
        `);
        console.log("pyodide-http loaded successfully");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error loading pyodide-http:", error);
      }
    }
  };


It's hard to know exactly why. Wonder if it's because too many workers are brought up. We had a similar concept at https://akuiper.com, which seems to work fine most of the time.
